# changing size of text of a particular item of listview in android

Tags: android-listview

I am getting prices of items from web service and setting them on list view items 
accordingly. Normally the price contains two digits, as the no of digits of price increases from three I am decreasing the size of text, works fine but on scrolling the
list the change in size of price(text view) applies on the rest of items's prices containing no of digits lesser than three.

here is my code in getview method

if(original_price.trim().length() > 3)
        {

```
        original_price_tv.setTextSize(10);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
if(original_price.trim().length() > 3) {

        original_price_tv.setTextSize(10);
}else{
           //Set your default size 20 or something
       original_price_tv.setTextSize(20);
}
```